# Where are identifiers like NSControlKeyMask defined

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift

Where are identifiers like `NSControlKeyMask`, `NSAlternateKeyMask` and `NSShiftKeyMask` defined? I need to compile Swift project using Objective-C library named [DDHotKey](https://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey) that contains the following code:

```
if (modifiers & NSControlKeyMask) {
    [final appendString:[characterMap objectForKey:@(kVK_Control)]];
}
if (modifiers & NSAlternateKeyMask) {
    [final appendString:[characterMap objectForKey:@(kVK_Option)]];
}
if (modifiers & NSShiftKeyMask) {
    [final appendString:[characterMap objectForKey:@(kVK_Shift)]];
}
```

This code gives me the following errors:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'NSControlKeyMask'
>
> Use of undeclared identifier 'NSAlternateKeyMask'
>
> Use of undeclared identifier 'NSShiftKeyMask'

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Modifier_Flags

Comment: @Martin R And? I don't see any clue about which framework should I link to. Adding Appkit.framework to the "Link Binary With Libraries" option didn't solve this issue

Comment: The doc shows they're static members of a struct, `NSEventModifierFlags`.  So you access them via `NSEventModifierFlags.ControlKeyMask` etc

Comment: @Airspeed Velocity Then it gives me "undeclared identifier" errors about `NSEventModifierFlags`

Comment: They are defined in NSEvent.h, which is part of Appkit. Are you importing AppKit?

Comment: Are you targeting the Mac or iOS?  In UIKit it’s `UIKeyModifierFlags.Control`.

Comment: I don't know the DDHotKey library, but `let mask = NSEventModifierFlags.ControlKeyMask` compiles just fine in a Cocoa OS X app, without any additional imports. You might have to get the underlying integer with `NSEventModifierFlags.ControlKeyMask.rawValue`.

Comment: @Martin R Did you create Objective-C or Swift project?

Comment: @ewrobinson Yep, I've already said it

Comment: @Airspeed Velocity Mac in this case

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "DDHotKey" sample project uses a *precompiled header file* "DDHotKey_Prefix.pch" with the contents

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#endif
```

so that `<Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` is automatically included by all Objective-C
sources. This in turn includes the Foundation and AppKit framework
headers.

New Xcode projects do not create precompiled headers files anymore.
If you just copied the sources files from the sample project to
a new project, your error will occur.

You could add a precompiled header file to your project,
but it actually seems to be sufficient to add

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
```

in "DDHotKeyUtilities.m".

Comment: I added a line `#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>` to the `DDHotKeyUtilities.m`, but now it fails with an error: `1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64`

Comment: @DominikPalo: I am sure that I tested it when posting the answer, but that is some time ago now. I will double-check it later when I have more time.

Comment: I removed the file `main.m` from DFHotKey group and now it works!